# Cold end coupler stuck on Bowden tube

Tags: creality-ender-3, bowden, ptfe-tube

I have a Creality Ender 3. I've unscrewed the coupler from the drive assembly, but can't get it loose from the tube.  The hot end coupler came free easily.

I compress the rubber gasket, but it stays tight.

Are these manufactured to be replaced every time?  My new Bowden tube didn't come with a new coupler.
I see that the couplers are sold with or without the tubing.

Comment: My couplers need a good hard tug to come off too. I'd be interested to see if you find a solution to get them off safely and without breaking anything.

Answer (score 4):

After depressing the retaining ring, try pushing the Bowden tube further in to the coupler. This should disengage the internal sprung clip, and allow removal of the Bowden tube.

Good quality pneumatic couplings should allow many insertion and removal cycles, although the couplings that Creality use have a reputation for early failure.

Comment: That's exactly the method I use to remove a bowden tube from the fitting. If it doesn't work for the OP, the last resort is destruction (cut it off).

Comment: You can always just push it all the way through.

Answer (score 2):

Success!  better tools and brute force did the trick.

I threaded the tube through the hole in a steel wrench handle, then clamped the end in sturdy forceps.  That gave me enough grip at each end to pull it apart.

Thanks for all the suggestions and for letting me know it IS supposed to come apart.

I also ordered Capricorn tubing, pneumatic couplers, and enough other printer toys...er, upgrades... to get free shipping.  Next time should be easy!

Comment: Predictably, now the coupler keeps coming loose from the tube.  Got a perfect print first, so at least I know I finally fixed the right thing.